# GET method for each table row having its own page

Tags: php, get

Say I have a database table titled "people" and under the column "names", I have "Bill", "Karen", and "Ted".

In my php file, I want to use just one template and using those rows, have a seperate page for each name (like "myfile.php?name=Bill"). From what I understand, I have to use GET, but I'm pretty still confused and inexperienced with that, so how would I go about obtaining my goal here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more and also show us what code you have in mind ?

Comment: Can you post examples of what you have tried and where specifically you are having problems? The SO community will help you debug your problems, we will not write your code for you.

Comment: What part specifically are you having a problem with? Accessing the variable from the query, or connecting to the database and searching?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a page based of a name in the get variable use this.
This basicly takes the name and takes it to the database and selects all field pretaining to that name, then you echo out the varibles and place them where you want a such.

```
<?php
$name = $_GET["name"];//gets name value from your url that you supplied in your post
$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","db-username","db-pass","db-name");
mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$name);
$sql = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM people WHERE names='$name'"));
$id = $sql['id'];//id would be a field in the people table
$age = $sql['age'];//age would be a field in the people table

echo '<h1>'.$name.'</h1>';
echo '<p>'. $id .'<br/>'. $ age .'</p>';

?>
```

Comment: I'm able to connect to the database. The pages I'm using have the sessions and template system integrated with phpBB forums. Here's an example of the code I'm using in my php file for the page. It works fine, but I'm very inexperienced with php, so I'm just having trouble understanding how to tell the page exactly what I want. `<?php
include "includes/phpbb.php";

$template->set_filenames(array(
 'body' => 'my_template.html',
));

$template->assign_vars(array(
    'ALT_STYLESHEET'    =>'my_style.css',
 'PAGE_TITLE'  =>'_______&#39;s Page',
)); 

$site->page_footer();
?>`

Comment: Mysql with mysqli function how bad

Comment: @NullPoiиteя Whoops that was a typo